# How to Select where in(Other table) but with modification

Tags: sql, t-sql

@ConfListTable is a table valued parameter (TVP) which has a list of confirmation codes. 
I want to select all the records from PmtHist table where the confirmation code is also in @ConfListTable. The following code works well for this; no problems.

```
Select * from PmtHist
Where Confirmation in(
    Select Str1 as ConfirmationCode
    From @ConfListTable
    )
```

My problem is this: The confirmation code in PmtHist occasionally has "voided" following the actually confirmation code. Like "ab321voided" But I really want those records too. How do I modify the above query to get the records that match either a record in @ConfListTable or matches @ConfListTable + 'voided'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick & easy way is to simply use REPLACE:

```
Select * 
from PmtHist
Where REPLACE(Confirmation, 'voided', '') in(
    Select Str1 as ConfirmationCode
    From @ConfListTable
)
```

Comment: I tested the speed of various queries; Using Replace actually was fastest. PmtHist has only several thousand records.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from PmtHist ph
where exists (
    select 1 from @ConfListTable
    where ph.Confirmation in (Str1, Str1 + 'voided')
)
```

Comment: I speed tested this 26 times and check how many milliseconds(ms): 4 x 46 ms; 6 x 60 ms; 16 x 63 ms. This was the slowest method for my situation.

Comment: @D_Bester, I like the one with `replace` too, though it is not "precise" solution, and may also catch rows, where 'voided' is not necessarily in the end, e.g. 'abvoided321'. If you know you have no such data, then surely faster alternative is the choice.

Answer (score 1):

For better performance, I suggest using two separate query

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.PmtHist t1
WHERE t1.Confirmation IN (SELECT t2.Str1 FROM @ConfListTable t2)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.PmtHist t1
WHERE t1.Confirmation IN (SELECT t2.Str1 + 'voided' FROM @ConfListTable t2)
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6eba9/1)

Comment: I'm not sure how this would scale to larger applications but this method was slower than using Replace for me. Replace varied between 13-16 milliseconds. Union All took longer. (out of 25 tests: 17 x 30-33 ms; 8 x 16 ms)

Answer (score 0):

Add a "where not in":

```
Select * from PmtHist
Where Confirmation in(
    Select Str1 as ConfirmationCode
    From @ConfListTable
    )
and Confirmation not in(
    <some list of voided confirmation
    )
```